# DCOM Exception in Event Viewer due to IIS related activities in remote machine

Tags: iis, dcom, microsoft.web.administration

I'm receiving Event ID 10028 (DCOM) in remote machine when fetching IIS Server Webistes and AppPools using Microsoft.Web.Administration dll:

DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer evserver1.domain.com using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     cbb0 (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe).

Any further help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Note:**
It works fine local machine. In Remote server also, the functionality of fetching IIS websites and AppPools is working but it triggers the DCOM exception as recorded in the Event Viewer.

Comment: The DCOM based remote mechanism you use was too old and did not work well in many cases. That's why https://github.com/microsoft/IIS.Administration was developed.

Comment: This problem may be related to the firewall. There was a similar discussion here that may provide some help for you: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28189261/DCOM-was-unable-to-communicate-with-the-computer-using-any-of-the-configured-protocols.html